# FsPlot for osx sierra

Tags: macos, highcharts, f#, fslab

I have got an error message with the following code: (example code from sudipta mukherjee)

```
#load "./packages/FsPlot.0.6.6/FsPlotBootstrap.fsx"
open FsPlot.Highcharts.Charting

// Logistic Regression
let z = [for i in -10. .. 10. -> (i,1./(1.+exp -i))]
z
 |> Chart.Spline
 |> Chart.WithTitle "Sigmoid Function"
 |> Chart.WithName "g(z)"
```

When I execute the code, I have got an error message in FSI:

```
Loading /eUSB/sync/fsharp/packages/FsPlot.0.6.6/FsPlotBootstrap.fsx]
namespace FSI_0008
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/eUSB/sync/fsharp/packages/FsPlot.0.6.6/./tools/chromedriver.exe',
    CommandLine='--port=53810', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Access denied
      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process p
    rocess) <0x11eab6f10 + 0x006f3> in <filename unknown>:0
    Stopped due to error
```

It seems the error is win32 related and FsPlot doesn't support OSX.

Please feel free to advise. What I should do to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrated source code to XPlot (part of FsLab package), it is running smoothly.

```
#load "./packages/FsLab.1.0.2/FsLab.fsx"
open XPlot.GoogleCharts

// Logistic Regression
let z = [for i in -10. .. 10. -> (i,1./(1.+exp -i))]

let options =
  Options
    ( title = "Sigmoid Function", curveType = "function",
      legend = Legend(position = "bottom") )

[z]
|> Chart.Line
|> Chart.WithOptions options
|> Chart.WithLabels ["g(z)"]
```